# How To Use a Regex Capture Result to Lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I am trying to use the result of the capture group to perform a look behind for a specific answer.

**Sample of Text:**

> 10) Once a strategy has been formulated and implemented, it is important that the firm sticks to it no matter what happens.
>
> Answer:  FALSE
>
> 11) Which of the following strategies does Tesla need to implement or achieve to gain a competitive advantage?
>
> A) imitate the features of the most popular SUVs on the market
>
> B) reinvest profits to build successively better electric automobiles
>
> C) sell advertising space on their cars' digital displays
>
> D) substitute less-expensive components to keep costs low
>
> Answer:  B

**Current Output:**

https://regex101.com/r/bLKmYX/1

It is currently outputting FALSE and B as the answers to these questions.

**Expected Output**

I would like it to output FALSE and *B) reinvest profits to build successively better electric automobiles*

**Current Regex Expression**

```
'^\d+\)\s*([\s\S]*?)\nAnswer:\s*(.*)'
```

How can I use the result of the second capture group, (B), to perform a lookbehind and get the whole answer?

Comment: You can't do that. Matching a regular expression works from left to right.

Comment: That's why they're called *back* references. You can't do a forward reference.

Comment: You can, but it won't be pretty. [Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/bLKmYX/2)

Comment: Another possibility: https://regex101.com/r/bLKmYX/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask for is not possible due to the fact that a captured value can only be checked after it was obtained.

You may try another logic: capture the answer letter and then match the same letter after `Answer:` substring using the backreference to the group value.

You may consider a pattern like

```
(?m)^\d+\)\s*((?:(?:(?!^\d+\))[\s\S])*?\n(([A-Z])\).*)$)?[\s\S]*?)\nAnswer:\s*(\3|FALSE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m7DrBT/1).

It has 4 capturing groups now, the first one containing the whole question body, then the second one containing the answer line you need, the third one is auxiliary (it is used to check which answer is correct), and the fourth one is the answer value.

**Details**

- `(?m)` - `^` now matches line start positions and `$` matches line end positions
- `^` - start of a line
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:(?:(?!^\d+\))[\s\S])*?\n(([A-Z])\).*)$)?[\s\S]*?)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:(?:(?!^\d+\))[\s\S])*?\n(([A-Z])\).*)$)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

    - `(?:(?!^\d+\))[\s\S])*?` - any char, 0 or more occurrences, that does not start a start of line, 1+ digits and then a `)` sequence
    - `\n` - a newline
    - `(([A-Z])\).*)` - Group 2: an ASCII uppercase letter captured into Group 3, then `)` char and then the rest of the line (`.*`)
    - `$` - end of line
  - `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `\nAnswer:` - a new line, `Answer:` string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\3|FALSE)` - Group 4: Group 3 value or `FALSE`.